# Can I cherry-pick commits in any order

Tags: git

Assume there are few commits in another branch:

```
11110bbc6
22227e37f
3333b0d08
444402071
55559292f
```

None of them are in the current branch. So, if I cherry-picky commit `333302071`, and is applied without a merge conflict; Can I later cherry pick earlier/later commits in any order?

Something like:

```
git cp 22227e37f
git cp 55559292f
git cp 11110bbc6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can. It may introduce conflicts, but in essence the order is up to you.

Comment: Do you mean to say if I pick 333, and then 111 - it may raise conflicts; And if I pick 111 and then 333 then it won't?

Comment: @Ajay, it all depends on whether changes in 333 depend on changes in 111 (and perhaps on changes in 222). If you modify file 111.txt in commit 111, 222.txt in commit 222, and 333.txt in commit 333, then all three changes are independent and can be cherry-picked in any order without introducing any conflicts.